# Aligning a div created using :before & :after horizontally to other elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox, pseudo-element

[image]

I am using `:before` to create a black circle (which should display white text exactly centered within, can't work out why it isn't white) and `:after` to display a dashed line (as seen). I'd like the black circle (with text inside it) to sit horizontally level with the input but I've been having issues with it as it also creates a big gap between it & the after dashed line. I've played around margin but I don't want to push elements above too far away.

```css
.progress-container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.progress-indicator {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  color: #fff;
}

.progress-indicator::before {
    content: "";
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.progress-indicator::after {
    content: "";
    height: 85px;
    border: 2px dashed #a9b4b8;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 49px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.input-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.input-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 2px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding: 0.375rem 1.75rem 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class=progress-container>
  <div class="progress-indicator">1</div>
  <div class="input-container">
    <div class="input-wrapper">
      <div>Input</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add a negative z-index to the balck circle, `   z-index:-1` :)

Comment: thanks. that does help the "hidden text" inside the circle, although it works in my codepen, it doesn't help in my application. Is there a possible workaround you know of so that I can be explicit about z-index so that this isn't an issue?

Comment: You don't have to use a before element for that. You can apply the circle styles direct to your progress-indicator.

Comment: good point. sorted - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caution: you have a typo in your `.progess-container` selector correct: `.progress-container`

Edited your CSS:

```css
.progress-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.progress-indicator {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
}

.progress-indicator::before {
    content: "";
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.progress-indicator::after {
    content: "";
    height: 85px;
    border: 2px dashed #a9b4b8;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  z-index: -2;
}

.input-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.input-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 2px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding: 0.375rem 1.75rem 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class=progress-container>
  <div class="progress-indicator">1</div>
  <div class="input-container">
    <div class="input-wrapper">
      <div>Input</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```